# Solving Congruences and CRT

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I have never really directly dealt with congruences until I was introduced to the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Although there are tons of different versions of this theorem out there, currently I am more interested in solving congruences.
I had some questions regarding steps that were used in solving the following congruent linear equation for $X_1$.

> $99X_1\equiv1\pmod8$
>
> Subtracting 96(which is a factor of 8 from both side)
>
> $3X_1\equiv1\pmod 8$ (Subtracting any factor of 8 on R.H.S is like subtracting $0$. So  R.H.S remains unchanged)
>
> Adding 8 gives:
>
> $3X_1\equiv(1+8) \pmod8$
>
> $3X_1\equiv9\pmod8$ so $X_1=3$

Now when 8 was added why was it only added to the R.H.S . I thought any factor of 8 whether being subtracted (or added?) on R.H.S is like subtracting or adding $0$ ?

Comment: Use `\pmod{a}` to get $\pmod{a}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Precisely* because adding $8$ modulo $8$ is the same as adding $0$, you can add $8$ to only one side and not change the congruence (just like you can add $0$ to only one side of $x=y$ to get $x=y+0$ and not change the equality).

Alternatively, since $0\equiv 8\pmod{8}$, you are adding the congruence $$3x_1\equiv 1\pmod{8}$$ to the congruence $$0\equiv 8\pmod{8}$$ to get $$3x_1+0 \equiv 1+8\pmod{8}.$$ This is like adding $x=a$ to $y=b$ in order to get $x+y=a+b$.

Comment: Oh okay , so we can add and subtract factors of 8 but from only one side at a time

Comment: @Rajeshwar: No, you can add **multiples** of $8$ to **either** side, or to **both** sides, at will, without disturbing the congruence.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up